# google-cloud-platform タグを新設し、google-cloud タグを deprecate していきたい

Tags: 討議, 完了, タグ, タグの別名の提案

現在 [google-cloud](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-cloud) というタグが 79 件の質問で使われているのですが、特にタグ wiki が整備されていません。

おそらくこのタグは Google Cloud Platform のために使われていると思うのですが、そうとすると英語版のタグ [[google-cloud-platform]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-cloud-platform) の名前と整合性がとれません。

英語版タグの別名を見ますと "google-cloud" が "google-cloud-platform" を親とする[別名として登録されています](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-cloud-platform/synonyms)。誤解を防ぐため、日本語版でも同様に [google-cloud-platform](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-cloud-platform) を親タグとして [google-cloud](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-cloud) を別名扱いにし、将来的には [google-cloud-platform](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-cloud-platform) にマージするようにしたいです。如何でしょうか。

Comment: [tag:google-cloud] を [tag:google-cloud-platform] の別名とすべく対応予定としました。
一週間程度、追加の意見を待った後に作業いたします。（回答に書きました通り、個人的には反対ですが、コミュニティーの意見を優先します）

Answer (score 1):

逆を提案します。つまり、[google-cloud](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-cloud) を残し、[google-cloud-platform](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-cloud-platform)を吸収させます。この件は提案から時間も経っているので、提案当時の文脈から離れて検討するのが良いと思います。

現在「Google Cloud Platform」と「Google Cloud」の関係は明確ではありませんが、文脈により下記のどちらかでしょう。

- 新旧: 「Google Cloud Platform」の新しい呼び方が「Google Cloud」である
- 包含: 「Google Cloud Platform」を含むサービス群全体が「Google Cloud」である

どちらだと考えても、「Google Cloud」の方を残すのがよいと思います。

#### 新旧の名称が有る場合は、新しい方が良い

企業のブランド名の変遷に忠実に従う必要も無いと思いますが、現在の日本語版では [google-cloud](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-cloud) の方が使われているので、丁度良いです。

#### 包含関係の二者をマージする際は、全体側を残す方が良い

これは状況によると思いますが、現在 [google-cloud](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-cloud) は86件あり、内容を精査するのは面倒です。全てを機械的にマージするならば、部分集合である方を全体側にマージするしかありません。また、全体側を部分集合の別名にすることはできません。

#### 参考

2016年、Googleはリブランディングを行ない、「Google Cloud Platform」は「Google Cloud」の一部となりました。

> Google Cloud spans every layer of the business, including all of Google Cloud Platform; ...
>
> —— [Introducing Google Cloud](https://cloud.googleblog.com/2016/09/introducing-Google-Cloud.html)

「Google Cloud」ブランドの普及に伴ない、Google自身は「Google Cloud Platform」という語の使用頻度を下げていった模様です。2022年、開発者向けのサイトでも、「Google Cloud Platform」を「Google Cloud」と呼ぶことが説明されました。

> Google Cloud Platform is now called Google Cloud
>
> —— [Introducing a new homepage for Google Cloud](https://cloud.google.com/blog/topics/developers-practitioners/introducing-new-homepage-google-cloud?hl=en)

Answer (score 1):

[google-cloud](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-cloud) を [google-cloud-platform](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-cloud-platform) の別名としました。

この提案ではマージは「将来的」とされているので、マージは行っていません。これは後日いずれかのタイミングで行なうことになります。